# Nominatim reverse geocoding Json format difference

Tags: openstreetmap, reverse-geocoding

I am trying to do reverse geocoding using open street maps. I am getting 2 different Json formats in the response.

For,
http://nominatim.openstreetmap.org/reverse?json_callback=cb&format=json&lat=12.975360&lon=80.190122&zoom=27&addressdetails=1
The Response contains neigbourhood,suburb etc,.

For,http://nominatim.openstreetmap.org/reverse?json_callback=cb&format=json&lat=40.119198&lon=-75.355764&zoom=27&osm_type=N&addressdetails=1
The Response contains county and other fields.

I do see that the OSM_TYPE is differing in both the response(node/way). Is there any way to restrict the type of response?I tried to add OSM_TYPE in the query string which doesn't seem to work. Is there anyother format that could be received?

Comment: cross-posted: http://gis.stackexchange.com/q/231747/23837

Comment: cross-posted: https://help.openstreetmap.org/questions/55051/reverse-geocoding-json-format-difference